# El Semáforo que he creado en Android está bloqueando la ejecución de mi programa

Tags: java, android, android-studio, hilos, asincronismo

Estoy intentando resolver con hilos y llamadas asíncronas unas requests que necesito hacer a un API en Android.

Voy a intentar poner un ejemplo simplificado sobre esto.

Resulta que obtengo las inversiones del usuario, y necesito hacer una llamada a cada una de estas para poder obtener todas las compras que ha hecho y poder sumar los costes de todas.

```
public class ControladorHome extends Fragment{

...

    private final AtomicInteger numeroDeHilosFinalizados = new AtomicInteger(0);//Para poder controlar los hilos.
    private Semaphore semaforo = new Semaphore(2);

    class HiloLlamadaRecuperarComprasInversion extends Thread {
        int id;
        Inversion inversion;

        HiloLlamadaRecuperarComprasInversion(int id, Inversion inversion) {
            this.id = id;
            this.inversion = inversion;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            recuperarComprasDeLaInversion(inversion, id);
        }
    }

    private void recuperarComprasDeLasInversiones() {
        int id = 0;

        List<HiloLlamadaRecuperarComprasInversion> listaHilos = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Inversion inversion : modeloHome.getInversionesUsuario()) {
            listaHilos.add(new HiloLlamadaRecuperarComprasInversion(id, inversion));
            id++;
        }

        for (HiloLlamadaRecuperarComprasInversion hilo : listaHilos)
            hilo.start();

        for (HiloLlamadaRecuperarComprasInversion thread : listaHilos) {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Salí del for.");//Comentarios internos a borrar.
        comprasRecuperadas();
    }

    private void recuperarComprasDeLaInversion(Inversion inversion, final int id) {

        System.out.println(String.format(getString(R.string.log_hilo_entra_funcion), id));//Comentarios internos a borrar.

        Call<RespuestaRecuperarCompras> call;
        call = modeloHome.inicializarCallRecuperarComprasDeLaInversion(inversion.getIdInversion());
        try {
            semaforo.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            System.out.println(String.format(getString(R.string.log_hilo_catch_aquire_semaforo), id));//Comentarios internos a borrar.
        }
        System.out.println(String.format(getString(R.string.log_hilo_pasa_semaforo), id));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<RespuestaRecuperarCompras>() {
            //Si no hay error al recibir la respuesta
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<RespuestaRecuperarCompras> call, @NotNull retrofit2.Response<RespuestaRecuperarCompras> response) {
                RespuestaRecuperarCompras comprasRecuperadas = response.body();

                modelo.almacenarComprasRecuperadasInversion(comprasRecuperadas.getCompraRecuperadaRecuperadas());

                semaforo.release();

                synchronized (numeroDeHilosFinalizados) {
                    System.out.println(String.format(getString(R.string.log_hilo_libera_semaforo), id, numeroDeHilosFinalizados.get()));//Comentarios internos a borrar.
                }
            }

            //Si hay error al recibir la respuesta
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<RespuestaRecuperarCompras> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                errorConexion();
                semaforo.release();
                synchronized (numeroDeHilosFinalizados) {
                    System.out.println(String.format(getString(R.string.log_hilo_libera_semaforo), id, numeroDeHilosFinalizados.get()));//Comentarios internos a borrar.
                }
            }
        });
    }
...
}
```

Estos son los Strings:

```
    <string name="log_hilo_entra_funcion">Hilo %d entró en la función</string>
    <string name="log_hilo_pasa_semaforo">Hilo %d pasó el semáforo</string>
    <string name="log_hilo_catch_aquire_semaforo">Hilo %d llegó al catch del semaforo.</string>
    <string name="log_hilo_libera_semaforo">Hilo %d ha liberado el semáforo, previamente han finalizado %d hilos</string>
    <string name="log_hilo_libera_semaforo_catch">En catch hilo %d ha liberado el semáforo, previamente han finalizado %d hilos</string>
```

Y cuando ejecuto el programa obtengo este Output:

```
/System.out: Hilo 2 entró en la función
I/System.out: Hilo 1 entró en la función
I/System.out: Hilo 0 entró en la función
I/System.out: Hilo 2 pasó el semáforo
I/System.out: Hilo 0 pasó el semáforo
W/zygote: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void libcore.io.Linux.connect(java.io.FileDescriptor, java.net.InetAddress, int)
```

Entiendo que se me está bloqueando el programa como si lo estuviera llamando desde el hilo principal, pero realmente creo que no es así por lo que no entiendo muy bien por qué se bloquea.

Comment: Si a lo que te refieres es que el hilo 1 no pasa el semáforo es porque cuando hace el `acquire` no se lo adjudican. Declaraste un semáforo de 2 hilos concurrentes, por lo tanto hasta que alguno de los otros 2 pase por el `release` el otro hilo en espera podrá continuar.

Comment: Claro, entonces el problema está en que no llega nunca al release, puede ser porque enqueque no se ejecuta en tareas que se encuentran en background threads.

Comment: Puede ser eso, o puede ser que ejecuta la petición y no vuelve, pero en definitiva los 2 hilos están detenidos en algún lugar. Yo nunca he hecho peticiones con `Call`s por lo tanto no tengo muy clara su dinámica, pero fíjate que la última línea de tu Output es un warning, esa podría ser la raíz del problema.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día! Me parece que el método

```
public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<RespuestaRecuperarCompras> call, @NotNull retrofit2.Response<RespuestaRecuperarCompras> response) {
```

se ejecuta incluso cuando ha fallado tu request. Podrías verificar el contenido de tu respuesta de la siguiente manera :

```
@Override
public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<RespuestaRecuperarCompras> call, @NotNull retrofit2.Response<RespuestaRecuperarCompras> response) {

   if (response.isSuccessful()) { //Verificamos si la respuesta fue exitosa
        String responseString = response.body();
        Log.d("Retrofit response -> ", responseString);
        // Realizar operaciones con la respuesta ( si se necesita )
    }
}
```

llamando al método `responde.isSuccess()` y también realizar `Log.d("Retrofit response -> ", responseString);` a tu  objeto body para visualizar que te esta devolviendo la llamada al endpoint, de no imprimir la respuesta puede que tu request al endpoint este fallando, en ese caso para visualizar el posible error, puedes usar break points en Android estudio y también agregar `Logs.d` en las diferentes partes del código, pero recomendaría utilizar break points, son más útiles.

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<RespuestaRecuperarCompras> call, @NotNull retrofit2.Response<RespuestaRecuperarCompras> response) {
            Log.d("Retrofit response -> ", response.toString()); // Que estas recibiendo de parte del endpoint
        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<RespuestaRecuperarCompras> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {

            t.printStackTrace() // Imprime el motivo del error

        }
```

Recomendación : Desacoplar un poco el código, no es una buena práctica tener tus llamadas a endpoints en tu Fragment y tu lógica para manejar los datos recibidos.

Referencias:

- https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-receive-plain-string-responses [ Como realizar una llamada a un endpoint]
- https://guides.codepath.com/android/consuming-apis-with-retrofit [ Algunos ejemplos de como realizar llamadas con retrofit]
- https://developer.android.com/studio/debug [ Como utilizar break points en Android Studio]

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugiero revisar [answer] para realizar respuestas en el sitio, recuerda también que tienes suficiente reputación para realizar comentarios, saludos.

Comment: ¿Como debería desacoplar el código? Estoy un poco verde con esto de llamadas y sincronización...

Comment: @MarcosUnzueta he actualizado mi respuesta con una mejor explicación :) . Con respecto desacoplar tu código, me refiero a separar las diferentes tareas que tienes. Para realizar esto te puedo recomendar unos ejemplos como el siguiente :
https://github.com/RaulitoGC/Technology-Store-App ,si quieres profundizar en el tema puedes revisar el blog de Antonio Leiva https://devexperto.com/clean-architecture-android/ que explica muchas cosas al respecto.